# How to pass a cell value or a function to the data of QUERY command in google spreadsheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

How can you pass a specific cell value or output of custom function (that returns string) as the "data" to a QUERY command?

For example instead of writing the A2:E6 in the following command:

QUERY(A2:E6,"select avg(A) pivot B")

I want to do something like this:

QUERY(A1,"select avg(A) pivot B")

Where A1 is reference to cell A1 which holds A2:E6 as the value.

For some reason QUERY command does not like the A1 there. But when you replace the A1 with the actual string value everything works just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### You can use the [`INDIRECT`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093377) function

```
=QUERY(INDIRECT(A1), "select avg(A) pivot B")
```

Which is exactly for this kind of use case.

There is even one for going the other way, [`ADDRESS`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093308), from cell address to string.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
function loadFormula() {
  const ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');//you may need to change sheet name
  const rg=sh.getRange('A1');
  const s = rg.getDisplayValue();//I used this method because it returns a strong
  const fs= '=QUERY(' + s + ',\"select avg(A) pivot B\")';
  sh.getRange(?).setFormula(fs);
}
```